# Adding padding / whitespace after some text

Tags: css, wordpress

I am attempting to customise the menu in a Wordpress.com site (belongs to a client).

The URL is: https://chainecharlotteorg.wordpress.com/

It's the main nav bar along the top of a site.

I can add a **CSS class** to the menu item. Using that class I have changed the background-color. But I want the background to have space at least before and after the manu item text. Padding has no effect.

I was able to get space before the text by defining the `width` to something wider than the text. This had the effect of creating space in front of the text. As shown here:

[image: Example]

But I have been unable to find a way to set some space after "Donate" so that the blue background extends beyond it. I would have thought padding would do this, but in this case it does not.

From the front end, here's the code involved:

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
<div class="menu-nav-menu-container">
<ul id="primary-menu" class="menu nav-menu" aria-expanded="false">
<li id="menu-item-157" class="donate menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-157">
<a href="https://chainecharlotteorg.wordpress.com/donate/">Donate</a>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-122" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-122">
<li id="menu-item-37" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-37">
<li id="menu-item-141" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-141">
<li id="menu-item-140" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-140">
<li id="menu-item-93" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-93">
<li id="menu-item-101" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-101">
<li id="menu-item-38" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-38">
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

With the following (from that) being the code specific to the "Donate" menu item:

```
<li id="menu-item-157" class="donate menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-157">
<a href="https://chainecharlotteorg.wordpress.com/donate/">Donate</a>
</li>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: you have the URL i can take a quick look else a jsfiddle would be good?

Comment: URL added. It's https://chainecharlotteorg.wordpress.com/

Comment: so you want them to be more spread out or the space on the left to be gone? as thats a :before element doing that? let me know what you want and il paste my answer below

Comment: Looks like I may have solved it. Silly over-sight. The class attributes I was testing were being overridden by others already in place. I is just a matter of adding the all-important `!important` qualifier.

Comment: use firebug add-ons for Mozilla and check if there multiple css fro same class. if multiple then either edit those css or you can add "!important" on you desire css

Answer (score 0):

A code snippet is the only way for anyone to really help you as well as to understand this issue. try

```
  margin-right: 30px;
```

Comment: This is all within the tight confines of a wordpress.com site. So I suspect I don't have access to the code in the normal way. But I suspect inspecting the the code from the front end (viewing https://chainecharlotteorg.wordpress.com/) may reveal what you're after. Margin and padding have no effect. I am assuming they are not class level attributes, but block level? (sorry, if my css terminology is incorrect).

Answer (score 0):

Well, as super obvious as this is, the solution was to use the `!important` property, in order to give priority to my class attributes over those defined elsewhere (beyond my reach) in the wordpress.com theme.

The following, therefore, now works as I was originally anticipating:

```
.donate {
    padding: 20px !important;
    background: blue;
}
```